# meteor add new data to existing collection

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, tabular

I am currently working on a application in Meteor where I read Data out of an Collection from MongoDB, in which i of course put data in, and save this data into a tabular table.
But the problem is, that after the first start of the app the Data doesnt refresh in the table, only the table header refresh, not the entries.
This is my code i currently have.

```js
//common.js
//code shared between client and server

Books = new Mongo.Collection("user");

TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Books = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "wahltable",
  collection: Books,
  columns: [
    {data: "vname", title: "Vorname"},
    {data: "nname", title: "Nachname"},
    {data: "standort", title: "Standort"},
 {data: "stimmen", title: "Stimmen"},
 {data: "anmerkung", title: "Anmerkung"}

  ]
});


//app.js from the server
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (Books.find().count() === 0) {
    var books = [
      {vname: "Anna", nname: "Muster" ,standort: "Das Modul", stimmen:"4", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      {vname: "Peter", nname: "Meier" ,standort: "BMHS", stimmen:"45", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      {vname: "Max", nname: "Muster" ,standort: "BMHS", stimmen:"66", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      {vname: "Moritz", nname: "Kaiser" ,standort: "BMHS", stimmen:"90", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      {vname: "Niklas", nname: "König" ,standort: "BMHS", stimmen:"123", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      {vname: "Victoria", nname: "Berger" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"90", anmerkung:"nichts"},
   {vname: "Hans", nname: "Berger" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"90", anmerkung:"nichts"},
   {vname: "Sepp", nname: "Hund" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"30", anmerkung:"nichts"},
   {vname: "Franz", nname: "Kross" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"940", anmerkung:"nichts"},
   {vname: "Miriam", nname: "Mayer" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"20", anmerkung:"nichts"},
   {vname: "Sandra", nname: "Meier" ,standort: "TGM", stimmen:"12", anmerkung:"nichts"},
      ];
    _.each(books, function (book) {
      Books.insert(book);
    });
  }
});
```

---

[image: CMD Snip]

This is how my cmd looks like while Meteor is running the app, i guess the autopublish error is meaningful but i dont know how to use this information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a write commands **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/)** that allow for the execution of bulk insert operations which are simply abstractions on top of the server and they make it easy to build bulk operations. These bulk operations come mainly in two flavours:

- **Ordered bulk operations** - These operations execute all the operation in order and error out on the first write error.
- **Unordered bulk operations** - These operations execute all the operations in parallel and aggregates up all the errors. Unordered bulk operations do not guarantee order of execution.

To use the bulk api, you need to get raw access to the collection and database objects in the npm MongoDB driver through rawCollection and rawDatabase methods on Mongo.Collection.

The following demonstrates this approach:

```
Books = new Meteor.Collection('books');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Books.find({}).count() === 0) {
            var bulkOp = Books.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
                counter = 0,
                books = [...]; // the books data array, shortened for brevity

            _.each(books, function (book) {

                bulkOp.insert(book);

                counter++;
                if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
                    // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
                    bulkOp.execute(function(e, rresult) {
                        // do something with result
                    });
                    bulkOp = Books.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                }
            }); 

            // Clean up queues
            if (counter % 1000 != 0){
                bulkOp.execute(function(e, result) {
                    // do something with result
                });
            }

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast answer, I wrote my code like you told me above, but is doesnt seem to help. It seems like it automatically loads the database entries and puts them in the colums on startup.
Is there something like a updateOnStartup() or refresh() method which i could use for this kind of problem?